# MODULE_INFO(srcversion, "HASH_VALUE_HERE") cause segmentation fault

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm learning to program linux device driver. I created a Hello World module which could be **make**'d without error on the first time. But whenever I **make** again , I run into an issue:

```
Makefile:714: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
WARNING: "mcount" [/home/anh/src/lkm/demo.ko] undefined!
/home/anh/src/lkm/demo.mod.c:39:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 MODULE_INFO(srcversion, "3251F071472830E8AC708F4");
 ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [/home/anh/src/lkm/demo.mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I reboot the computer I can compile it successfully, but only the first time.
Can anyone give me an advice ?
Here is the Makefile file:

```
obj-m += demo.o
ccflags-y = -w 
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Just do what the error message suggests: "Please submit a full bug report ...". But before submitting a bug try to eliminate the problems noted in the first two strings, about `CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG` and about `mcount`.

Comment: Update your compiler and other tools